# Can't Split Items in a List Correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm loading items from a CSV file into a list.  Now, I'm trying to split the list on each newline, and i'm getting this.

Here is my code.

```
mylist=[]
file = open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\test.csv') 
for line in file: 
    mylist.append(line)


import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                        'Server=server_name;'
                        'Database=db_name;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

#print(cnxn)
for item in mylist:
#for line in mylist:
    print(item)
    sql_for_df = 'select * ' + item.split(',')
    item_order = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df , cnxn)
    order_details = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df , cnxn)
    orders = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df , cnxn)


from functools import reduce
dfs = [item_order, order_details, orders]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='OrderID'), dfs)
```

This:

```
print(item)
```

Gives me this:

```
ItemOrder

Order Details

Orders
```

But, when I try to concatenate it, like this:

```
sql_for_df = 'select * ' + item.split(',')
```

I'm getting this error.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

It's almost like the list is split correctly and then it goes back to the original format from the list.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you are giving a list not an element of a list

Comment: This `item.split(',')` will return a `list`. you may use `map("".join,item.split(','))`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split ``Return a **list** of the words in the string``

Comment: Yeah, I read the docs.  Something is still off here because the list is not getting split correctly.  When I print sql_for_df, I get this: 'select * Orders\n'

Answer (score 0):

After another look, I figured it out myself.  Thanks for the down-votes!!

Here is the final, working, solution.

```
mylist=[]
file = open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\test.csv') 
for line in file: 
    mylist.append(line)


import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                        'Server=server_name;'
                        'Database=db_name;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

for item in mylist:
        #print(item)
        sql_for_df = 'select * from ' + item
        orders = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df , cnxn)
        print(orders)


from functools import reduce
dfs = [item_order, order_details, orders]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='OrderID'), dfs)
```